# How do I split a large WinRAR file using WinRAR?

Tags: windows, winrar

I have a .rar file, (already compressed) and I need to split it.  Can this be done through the WinRAR UI?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using WinRAR.

Open WinRAR window and navigate to the folder which your file is located in that WinRAR window.

**Right click** on your RAR file and select "**Add files to archive**" (alternatively you can press Alt+A).

In the opened window, give a new name to your to-be-split file (e.g. Archive_2.rar). Then, under "**Compression Method**", select "**Store**". Input your desired value inside "**Split to volumes, bytes**" box, click **OK** and you're done.

Comment: Cool idea... "store" the already compressed data.

Answer (score 8):

Open WinRAR
Select **Tools --> Wizard**
Select **Create New Archive**
Select Original **filename.rar** file
Enter the destination folder and new archive file name
Enter the **required size (500mb, 700mb,2 gb, 4.4 gb)**
Click **Finish** button.

Automatically create all archive files in selected folder.

Comment: Good ideas above, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a big 260GB RAR file (backup from a server) and I wanted to split the archive into smaller 2GB units.

I went to the Tools menu and ran the Archive Conversion utility.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Big archive file you want to convert into Multi-volumes, and Press ALT + Q or select 'Convert Archive' from the Tools Menu.

Then Click on 'Compression' button towards the middle of the screen on the Right side, and chose the desired size for the Multi-Volume archives.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you already have a large archive and need to split it up -- for example maybe you unexpectedly hit the Github 100 MB limit -- this is the simple and straightforward approach

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click the files you want to add into your archive and click "Add to archive..", on the Compression method click "Store" and on the "Split to volumes, size" type the size you want. You can also change it to **B**ytes, **K**ilo**B**ytes, **M**ega**B**ytes and **G**iga**B**ytes